# How to avoid the automatic _id so it only makes 1 Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the schema:

```
var RdvSchema = new Schema({
  _idRdv: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  patient:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref:'Patient'} ,
  pro: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref:'Pro'},
  motif: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Pro'},
  domicile:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Pro'},
 }
```

Here's the data:

```
var rdv1 = new Rdv({
  _idRdv: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  patient: patient1.name,
  pro: pro1.name,
  motif: pro1.Consultation.Motif,
  domicile: pro1.Consultation.Domicile
});
```

And here's the shell:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.rdvs.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c28817f81e91061044ddc7"),
    "_idRdv" : ObjectId("59c28817f81e91061044ddc6"),
    "patient" : "Maxime",
    "pro" : "Ben",
    "domicile" : true,
    "__v" : 0
```

How can I prevent this :  **"_id" : ObjectId("59c28817f81e91061044ddc7")** from happening?

Answer (score 2):

"_id" is the unique identifier for any mongodb document. You **cannot** make it not generated in a document.

But you can remove it in your output of the find as below:

```
db.rdvs.find({}, {'_id': False}).pretty()
```